# From server comes HTML instead of XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rest, nsurlsession

I'm sending GET request to server, but data comes in HTML instead of XML format. How can I solve this problem?

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN"];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url
       completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
           NSLog(@"DATA %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);
           NSLog(@"RESPONSE %@",response);


       }] resume];
```

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. For example, is the site supposed to return XML? Do other implementation (e.g. Android) get XML? Are you the owner of the server? What does the HTML say? (error, 404)

Comment: The site appears to already return XML anyway, are you *sure* you're getting HTML back?

Comment: Yes, i'm exactly know, that it is HTML. Moreover this html data shows main page of this site

Comment: If you look at response, you'll see `"Content-Type" = "application/xml; Charset=windows-1251";`. So `NSLog(@"String = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding]);` gives results... I don't use NSXMLParser (or whatever you want to parse it), but you may have to change the encoding (on server side, or maybe yourself in the completion handler).

Answer (score 0):

encoding might have been an issue?

Using NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding gives correct data.

Following code returns xml data for me:

```
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN"];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Got response %@ with error %@.\n", response, error);
            NSLog(@"DATA:\n%@\nEND DATA\n",
                  [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                        encoding: NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding]);
        }] resume];
```